# Netsuite reallocation log issue

Tags: javascript, logging, netsuite

update 2: this code works pt will not show original values, i think its because of it being before submit and after submit, dont know if this can be solved

```
//outputs all items remaining on an realocate thingy
var STOIC = STOIC || {};

STOIC.example = (function () {
    var exports= {};
        // shows original values, does not work, only shows new value.
        function beforeSubmit(type, form, request) {
        var record = nlapiGetOldRecord();
        var itemID = nlapiGetFieldValue('item');
        var lineCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('order');
        var totalqtyCom = nlapiGetFieldValue('quantitycommitted');
            for ( var i = 1; i < lineCount + 1; i++ )
            {
            var qtyCom = nlapiGetLineItemValue('order', 'quantitycommitted', i);
            var orderNum = nlapiGetLineItemValue('order', 'ordernumber', i);
            var qtyRem = nlapiGetLineItemValue('order', 'quantityremaining', i);
                if(i == 1)
                {
                nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "STOIC.example.beforeSubmit",
             "START-BEFORE:" + itemID + ":Order " + orderNum + ", qtyRem " + qtyRem + ", qtyCom" + qtyCom);
                }
                else
                    if(i == lineCount)
                    {
                        nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "STOIC.example.beforeSubmit",
                        "END-BEFORE:" + ":Order " + orderNum + ", qtyRem " + qtyRem + ", qtyCom" + qtyCom);
                    }
                else
            nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "STOIC.example.beforeSubmit",
            "Order " + orderNum + ", qtyRem " + qtyRem + ", qtyCom" + qtyCom);  
            }


        }

    //shows the new value
    function afterSubmit(type, form, request) {
        var record = nlapiGetOldRecord();
    var itemID = nlapiGetFieldValue('item');
        var lineCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('order');
    var totalqtyCom = nlapiGetFieldValue('quantitycommitted');
            for ( var i = 1; i < lineCount + 1; i++ )
            {
            var qtyCom = nlapiGetLineItemValue('order', 'quantitycommitted', i);
            var orderNum = nlapiGetLineItemValue('order', 'ordernumber', i);
            var qtyRem = nlapiGetLineItemValue('order', 'quantityremaining', i);
                if(i == 1)
                {
                nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "STOIC.example.afterSubmit",
             "START-AFTER:" + itemID + ":Order " + orderNum + ", qtyRem " + qtyRem + ", qtyCom" + qtyCom);
                }
                else
                    if(i == lineCount)
                    {
                        nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "STOIC.example.afterSubmit",
                        "END-AFTER:" + ":Order " + orderNum + ", qtyRem " + qtyRem + ", qtyCom" + qtyCom);
                    }
                else
            nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "STOIC.example.afterSubmit",
            "Order " + orderNum + ", qtyRem " + qtyRem + ", qtyCom" + qtyCom);  
            }
    }
    function beforeLoad() { // will not fire
        nlapiLogExecution("DEBUG", "STOIC.example.beforeLoad",
                        "testing?");
    }

    exports.beforeSubmit = beforeSubmit;
    exports.afterSubmit = afterSubmit;
    exports.beforeLoad = beforeLoad;
    return exports;
}



)();
```

UPDATE: So for the reallocation page id want it to
-Count the number of lines
- use a for loop to output order number, customer and quantity committed.
-I'd like for this to run both before submit and after submit. That should get it to show me what the original quantity committed were and the new quantity committed are now.
useing 
    var lineCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('quantitycommitted');

### seems like it would get me the number of lines but is getting out '-1' instead.

Original
I'm a new admin and i've been trying to figure out this long term issue we have been having.
Id need to write a script in the reallocation item page so that whenever somebody changes a value on that page, the
execution log spits out the item that was changed, the previous value of qty committed and the new value of qty committed.
Ive looked around on netsuit, support sites and forums and haven’t found anything helpful.
Im not sure what netsuite internally would call qty committed.

this is as far as i've gotten
api 1.0

```
var STOIC = STOIC || {};
STOIC.example = (function () {
  var exports= { };
  function beforeSubmit(item) {
    var NumLines= nlapisGetLineItemCount(‘item’);
    for ( var I = 1; i < NumLines + 1; i++)
      // something along the lines of…
      // if ( original quantity* != current qty*)
      //nlapiLogExecution(“debug”, ???, itemname* “old:” + original qty + “ new:” + new qty*);
})();
```

*what does netsuite call these internally?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can find the available standard fields and sublists available to SuiteScript in the records browser. [Here](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/reallocateitem.html) is the documentation on the Reallocate Items transaction type.

- Note: The link is using the standard system.netsuite.com/.... url. Modify it accordingly to work for whatever data center you are logged into (i.e. system.na1, system.na2, system.sandbox, etc)

Comment: So im able to get it to output  the item id but for whatever reason it will not give me the total number of lines. 
---
var lineCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('quantitycommitted'); 
---
Id like to have it loop and go to every line and spit out the order number, customer and quantity committed.
Looking at other examples, using that line of code should get me something besides '-1'

Comment: If you review the documentation in the link I provided, you will see that there is only 1 sublist on the Reallocate Items page, and that sublist is called 'orders'. nlapiGetLineItemCount() requires that the sublist internal id be passed in, and 'quantitycommitted' is not a sublist.

Comment: I just figured that out, thanks.
I finished the main part of the script and im only able to get it to show the altered values of the quantity, not what the original quantities were. Im not sure if this can be corrected because the script can only fire before submit and after submit. (see new update)

Comment: nlapiGetOldRecord() - Available in beforeLoad, beforeSubmit, and afterSubmit user event scripts.

Comment: with
-
record = nlapiGetOldRecord()
...
var qtyCom = record.nlapiGetLineItemValue('order', 'quantitycommitted', i);
-
it says "Cannot call method "nlapiGetLineItemValue" of null "
for reallocation im not sure that it's considered a record. It seems that its more like a filtered saved search.

Comment: You are using the wrong format of the api call. When dealing with a NetSuite object (in this case an nlobjRecord), the call drops the 'nlapi' portion. The call would be record.getLineItemValue(group, name, linenum). Are you sure that nlapiGetOldRecord() is not returning the record object? Have you logged it out?

Comment: i tried get old record and get current record (for testing) and old record returns "TypeError: Cannot call method "getLineItemValue" of null... " 
get current record will call the 'after' part of the reallocate. I have been logging it (code in main post) and ive gotten the same output on the before and after logs.